# Как изменить стандарт, который использует компилятор по умалчанию? (с, с++)

Tags: c++, linux, c, clang

Обнаружил, что clang++ использует 98 стандарт по умолчанию, хотя поддерживает гораздо более новые стандарты. Как изменить стандарт по умалчанию в clang и clang++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang использует совместимые с gcc ключи. Вот официальный список: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-std, вот список стандартов у gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards

Используйте `-std`. Например, `-std=c++17`.

---

Кажется, нет возможности установить стандарт по умолчанию, глобально. Я обычно использую мэйкфайлы с `CXXFLAGS`. Если вы компилируете с командной строки под линуксом, возможно, вам поможет `alias`:

```
alias clang++="clang++ -std=c++17"
```

Comment: Но это не меняет установки *по умолчанию*...

Comment: я это знаю: я хочу чтобы компилятор сам по умолчанию использовал другой стандарт

Comment: Ах, _по умолчанию_! Боюсь, что это невозможно, но сейчас поищу в документации.

Comment: Это возможно. Это можно сделать через spec files, но обычно овчинка не стоит выделки...

Comment: @AnT: Никогда о таком не слыхал, напишете ответ?

Comment: @AnT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638901/276994

Comment: Да, похоже я не прав. Не судьба. Я думал про gcc, наивно полагая что clang и в этом совместим.

Comment: @AnT: Жаль! Ну что же, отрицательный результат — тоже результат. К тому же, я узнал о spec-файлах в gcc, так что для меня оказалось вдвойне полезно.